# Finding the exterior dimensions of a USB type-c receptacle

Tags: usb, usb-c, enclosure

I'm going to be using [this USB type-c receptacle](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/USB-Connectors_SHOU-HAN-TYPE-C16PIN_C393939.html) for my project.  For this project, I need to make a cutout in my enclosure to make this receptacle fit.  I consulted the data sheet and found technical drawings I thought would make this a simple matter.  Unfortunately I was not able to decipher the drawings.  I looked quite hard and could not find the exterior shape of the receptacle including the radius on the corner bends.  My question is if this is a standard shape that I can find elsewhere or if I am just that bad at reading the diagram and that the exterior shape is described in the datasheet.

Comment: The datasheet does have external height and width, but I couldn't find corner radii.  You could probably get a decent estimate by scaling the drawing (normally a no-no but in this case probably close enough). But: If they are not specified on the datasheet, it might mean they are not tightly controlled and may vary part to part. Are you tied to this part or could you change to one with a better datasheet?

Answer (score 3):

[image: USB-C]
Width: 8.94mm
Width before the housing bends: 6.69mm (-0.055mm or +0.045mm)
Height: 3.26mm (+-0.15mm)
Height before the housing bends: 0.70mm (might be 0.6mm but with the bigger size, the bend will always be big enough. Now draw this in your preffered 2D or 3D modelling software and draw an arc between the lines before the bending. Make sure you place the lines beofre bending on the correct distances from eachother.
[image: Rought sketch]
Black lines have length: 6.69mm horizontally
Blue lines have length: 0.70mm vertically 
Draw then the Arc, displayed in red in my sketch. 
This should be good enough for your project. If you need the exact measurements, then emailing the manufacturer is the only way, because after looking for 10 minutes through various sources and datasheets, there is nowhere a mention fo the radius of the bends. Perhaps someone else has a good source, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

After 20 minutes of googling I found one manufacturer publishing a drawing with radius **R1.20** for [U06-CFXX5R-W069 receptable](https://www.bsc-elec.com/product/Surface-Mount-Waterproof-16Pin-USB-Type-C-Female-Connector-Based-on-IP67-H590mm.html) - this looks correct.

Relevant part shown below. Keep in mind thet outside dimmensions are for the gasket:

[image: squared-off connector]

I also checked the [USB-C spec from USB-IF](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-cable-and-connector-specification-release-23) and drawings there, for both male and female connectors, contain radius that isn't "squared off". They recommend a full-radius instead as shown on the `Figure 3-1` in `USB Type-C Spec R2.3 - October 2023 REDLINE versus R2.2` reproduced below:
[image: usb-if connector]

All in all, it doesn't seem crucial, as it seems like a lot of manufacturers "eyeball" this. I checked about 10 devices at hand, and amusingly almost every single one is a bit different.